# Using usort to sort json output

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, usort

I have below json outout. Can anyone please suggest how to sort this according to "no_count" column?

```
$arr= {"UserHeader":[

{"id":"154", "no_count":15},
{"id":"155", "no_count":11},
{"id":"158", "no_count":13},
{"id":"159", "no_count":31},
{"id":"164", "no_count":11}

]}
```

I have used USORT but no luck. The code is not working and give me the same array without sorting.

```
 usort($arr, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
return $a->no_count > $b->no_count ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
 });                                                                      

 print_r($arr);
```

Might be a small formatting error.

Thanks

Comment: If this is the actual code, I would expect you to be seeing errors as PHP has no concept of inline JSON notation. The other issue appears to be that you don't account for all the objects under the `UserHeader` key / property.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some corrections :

```
$arr = json_decode('{"UserHeader":[
{"id":"154", "no_count":15},
{"id":"155", "no_count":11},
{"id":"158", "no_count":13},
{"id":"159", "no_count":31},
{"id":"164", "no_count":11}
]}');

usort($arr->UserHeader, function ($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
    return $a->no_count > $b->no_count ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
});

print_r($arr);
```

It should work as expected.